# Vaadin Flow app switch between light and dark modes automatically

Tags: themes, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Vaadin Flow 14 ships with light and dark versions of its two bundled themes, *Lumo* and *Material*.

And now [browsers can ask the host OS for the user’s preference for light or dark modes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50840168/642706).

Is there a way to have a Vaadin app automatically use the light or dark theme variant per the user’s wishes?

Marcus Hellberg wrote [a helpful post on how to switch light/dark mode](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/toggle-dark-theme) theme variants programmatically. I am wondering if Vaadin 14 might be able to switch automatically now that the user preference is detectable from within the browser.

If not, perhaps Someone could show Java code for inquiring about the user’s preference from server-side Java code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) API to listen for changes to the [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) media query standardized in [Media Queries Level 5](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-5/#prefers-color-scheme). See [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=prefers-color-scheme) for browser support.

That CSS [media feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_features) of color scheme preference has 3 possible values: `no-preference`, `light`, and `dark`. The code below looks for a match on `dark`.

1. Put the JavaScript code shown below into `/frontend/prefers-color-scheme.js`
2. On your main view, add the annotation `@JsModule("prefers-color-scheme.js")`

```js
let mm = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
function apply() {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("theme",mm.matches?"dark":"");
}
mm.addListener(apply);
apply();
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/emarc/690eb2659c8b51cb895716914d65ec19

Comment: IntelliJ 2019.1 gives a warning on that `addListener` call, saying “Deprecated symbol used”.

Comment: Wow! That does work dynamically. On my first reading of your code, I did not understand that the listener is ongoing. So I gave it a try. I switched my Mac in macOS Mojave `System Preferences` > `General` > `Appearance`, and sure enough my Vaadin web app page switches to Light Mode or Dark Mode immediately alongside the native running apps.

Comment: See [this video screen clip](https://vimeo.com/381286135) demo of user switching Mac from Light to Dark Mode and back again, and the Vaadin web app changing automatically.